# Does Bane have a Mole Machine in DC canon?

Tags: dc, lego, bane

Lego seems to have paired Bane up with a mole machine. In [several Batman Lego games](http://legomarveldc.wikia.com/wiki/Bane's_Mole_Machine) and now in a [couple](http://lego.wikia.com/wiki/6860_The_Batcave) [of](http://www.lego.com/en-gb/dccomicssuperheroes/products/mighty-micros-robin-vs-bane-76062) sets.

Is there any canonical support for Bane having such a machine, or is it something Lego thought up on their own?

Comment: He did whole bunch of  digging under Gotham in *The Dark Knight Rises*.

Answer (score 2):

At this time Bane has this machine in *LEGO Batman 2: DC Super Heroes* and *LEGO Batman 3: Beyond Gotham*. The machine is buildable and playable in regular Lego editions of the DC universe as well as Lego Dimensions micro version.

[image: Lego Dimensions mole machine]

While Bane has used some method to place bombs under Gotham and collapse the subway tunnels, it is not currently known what tool he used. This weapon specifically has not yet been used in any plotline within the Batman canon.

Comment: He did whole bunch of digging under Gotham in *The Dark Knight Rises*. Why not with a Lego Mole Machine?!?